# Android App Preference

Tags: android

I have this android app with user login and app settings.

app settings are save in default location `com.package_preference.xml`

when user logins. he or she can set the app settings like notification. or vibrate.

my problem is when another user logins every app settings set by the last user logged in will be use since it was stored localy.

any ways to handle this issue? or better ways to avoid this problems?

I was thingking saving that file on sqlite but that was a lot of work to do.

or name the preference file like `user_id_preference.xml` but i dont think this is feasible since app preference are save as  `com.package_preference.xml`

Comment: you can clear prefrence when new user logs in..

Comment: yeah. i tried that two but the problem is when the last user logins again

Comment: save the login user details...say last 5 users details..and when user log in..just check with your saved data

Comment: use SharedPreferences and store different user's preference separately using different keys for different users.

Comment: Ok. ill try you suggestions. .,Thanks